# django model admin add form gets stuck

Tags: python, django, admin

Consider this

```
@admin.register(Personal, site=admin_site)
class PersonalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ChangePersonalForm
    add_form = AddPersonalForm

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if not obj:
            self.form = self.add_form

        return super(PersonalAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

The first time you try `creating` or `changing` an object, it will work fine.
But, after you `create` the object, every time you try to `change` an object, you will get the `add_form` instead of the `form`

I fixed that by adding an else block

```
@admin.register(Personal, site=admin_site)
class PersonalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_form = ChangePersonalForm
    add_form = AddPersonalForm

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if not obj:
            self.form = self.add_form
        else:
            self.form = self.change_form

        return super(PersonalAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

As if there was some sort of `class` caching.

Anyone knows why?

Comment: I've tried without override the `get_form` method... and it works smoothly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All in Django are templates. When assigning custom form to the Admin-site form not only change the functionality of how django receives the data but also you are changing the template that is used in each request, so when creating and updating for the first time is ok, but once you assigned the custom form this is used by default to actions of the form. It's necessary to contemplate the two cases doing so it's necessary to reassign the default template (form) that you are using and not remain in previous template (add_form). This does Django internally. Ref https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1006

Note: If you use a custom form not use "form" variable to reassing a custom form, instead form use change_form

```
@admin.register(Personal, site=admin_site)
class PersonalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_form = ChangePersonalForm
    add_form = AddPersonalForm

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if not obj:
            self.form = self.add_form
        else:
            self.form = self.change_form

        return super(PersonalAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```