# Django admin page copy ManyToMany related field from one model to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, django-admin-actions

I am trying to write a scheduling app. Here there are multiple `workers` and I create a `group` of workers. The Group is used as a template to create schedule.

When I create a `Schedule` object I want to take input of a `Group` object and copy the `members` from the `Group` object to the `Schedule` object. I don't want to give a ForeignKey to the `Group` object itself because the workers might change for a single day, whereas the group should be left intact as a template.

**models.py**

```
class Worker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Worker, blank=True)

class Schedule(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
    date = models.DateField()
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Worker, blank=True)
```

I understand this can be done easily with `views` and html templates. But I am trying to do the same under `admin` page. I have a form for `Schedule` and registered it in `admin.py`

**forms.py**

```
class CreateScheduleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    group = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Schedule
        fields = ( 'date', 'start_time', 'end_time')
```

**admin.py**

```
@admin.register(Schedule)
class ScheduleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CreateScheduleForm
```

I don't quite understand how to receive this input and process the `Group` object instance and copy the `members`. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a number of ways to approach this. One approach could be overriding the `save_model` method in your `ScheduleAdmin`:

```
@admin.register(Schedule)
class ScheduleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CreateScheduleForm

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        
        sched = form.save()
        group = form.data.get('group')
        for worker in Group.objects.get(pk=group).members.all():
            sched.members.add(worker)
```

Please be aware that this is only a very quick and dirty example, adding the members from the selected group each time you save the object. If you modify an existing schedule the `obj` arg in the method gives you that instance and the `change` arg would be `True`. You might want to implement some additional checks and remove existing members before you add the members of the group in cases where you modify an existing schedule.

More details on the admin site, exisiting methods and what you can do can be found in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That worked

Comment: A followup question. I am trying to change the "add" or insert view and keep the "change" or edit view intact. I know we can do this by creating a `add_form_template` and extending the admin/change_form.html in the template. Is this the best way of doing it or is there any other "quick and dirty" easier way of doing this? Thanks in advance

Comment: This answer is exactly what I wanted :) Never mind the question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44877651/django-model-admin-add-form-gets-stuck